# Logitech G-Hub script does not detect my left click input. (Arg 1)

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I got it working yesterday and today it doesn't work anymore.  I tried with the default script from Logitech G Hub but `MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 1` does not show up. It shows 2-11 just fine, why does it happen?

I tried to Run As Administrator but it still does not work. How to fix this?

All my buttons work perfectly fine just Lua Script from G-Hub or LGS are not detecting the Left Click Input.

```lua
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n");
end
```

Outputs:

```
(13:34:44) Script Loaded ()
Event: PROFILE_DEACTIVATED Arg: 0
Event: PROFILE_ACTIVATED Arg:0
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 2
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED Arg: 2
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 3
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED Arg: 3
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 9
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED Arg: 9
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED Arg: 5
Event: MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED Arg: 5
```

[Original screenshot of the script and the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1yQt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly enable processing of LMB events:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
  ....
end
```